# Avoiding "Target type 'type name' is not convertible to base type System.String"

Tags: xml, xaml, resharper

I am using ReSharper 6.1.1 and having the [solution wide analysis](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_analysis.html#Solution-Wide_Analysis) enabled in my project shows up with an error:

> Target type 'CustomControls.XSButton' is not convertible to base type System.String

The code compiles and runs fine since a built in TypeConverter in WPF takes care of this, shortly described in a [ReSharper bug report](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-180711).

Note that the `XSButton` is declared in an assembly in my solution - It's not a WPF built in type.

This is the xaml code that causes this error at the `<Style>` tag.

```
<CustomControls:XSButton
        Content="i" Grid.Column="2" Command="ApplicationCommands.Help"
        Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" ToolTip="Show Help" Visibility="Collapsed">
    <CustomControls:XSButton.Style>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type CustomControls:XSButton}">
             <Setter Property="Height" Value="26"/>
             <Setter Property="Width" Value="26"/>
             <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="13"/>
         </Style>
   </CustomControls:XSButton.Style>
</CustomControls:XSButton>
```

Is there any way to avoid this:

- The attribute expects a `System.String` so what string literal should I *replace* the type instance with?
- Is there any way to *ignore* this ReSharper error?
- Is thare any way to *rearange* the xaml to avoid this error? E.g. se attributes directl rather than using setters?

**EDIT**

The problem only appears when the style tag is *inside* a tag of the same type, in this case "foo:Bar". Note that I'm open o avoiding this error any way possible? Perhaps completely rearrange the xaml code.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's a bug in R# 6.1.1. Issue is already fixed and a fix will be available in a next major R# version. Sorry for the inconvenience.

You can really simply workaround it like this:

```
<foo:Bar Command="ApplicationCommands.Help">
  <!-- just use the separate resource for base style: -->
  <foo:Bar.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="baseStyle" TargetType="{x:Type foo:Bar}">
    </Style>
  </foo:Bar.Resources>

    <foo:Bar.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type foo:Bar}"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource baseStyle}">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        </Style>
    </foo:Bar.Style>
</foo:Bar>
```

Just put the `BasedOn` style declaration into separate resource.

Comment: In this code snippet you use a WPF built in type, while I use a type declared in my assembly.

Comment: @ContolFlow hi, I added some more information. Seems like it shoule be possible to avoid this some how. Like not using setters, but assigning the properies immediately or somethig...

Answer (score 1):

To just hide the error for ReSharper's solution wide analyzation you can set your error to be ignored.
Open ***Soultion Errors Window*** by *ReSharper->Windows->Soultion Errors Window*.
Right-click annoying error and select ***Ignore Error***.

Here is a screenshot with another error as an example:

[image]

If you want to enable the error again you can revert the error ignoring:

[image: Stopping ignoring error]