# Exclude ReSharper error for "Resource not found" inside Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, resharper, static-code-analysis

I have an **MVC2 application** and use **ReSharper 6.1** - I've heavily customised the Code Inspection Severity and edited what it decides to show as errors, warnings, suggestions and hints, but I cannot seem to stop it from telling me that a specific resource is missing when utilising a **HTMLHelper**.

So, for instance:

`<img src="<%:Url.Content("~/Resources/Image12345.jpg")%>" />`

I get an error on every line similar to the above telling me that the path above does not exist - which at *design time* it does not, but during the build process all of these views are XCOPY'd to a location which contains all of the resources, such as the images, so at the point of running the application all of this path resolution is correct. Because of working in a team of people, some of which are new to ReSharper, I wanted to exclude this error from appearing as it may cause colleagues of mine to start fiddling with something that isn't broken.

ReSharper obviously doesn't know that this isn't an issue and it has no way of knowing which is why I want to turn off this specific bit of analysis. I've found on the whole that ReSharper is massively customizable and in version 6.1 under **Inspection Severity** there are some new **MVC** options, which have proved useful - but I can see no way of turning off the inspection for this.

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well - It seems that this particular type of inspection is not currently catered for. I'll see if I can request it with JetBrains and hopefully more granular MVC inspection will be included in the future.

Cheers guys

Answer (score 1):

There are few options, press ALT+ENTER.

1. Suppress inspection "Path Error" with comment. You can suppress whole block of code, not only each of tag.
2. Suppress inspection "Path Error" at all at whole project.
3. There is new feature of 6.1 - path mapping, but it seems broken in conjunction with MVC.

Comment: Thanks - I'll give this a try tomorrow, it's the suppressing at whole project/solution that I want

Comment: Ok, ALT+ENTER options on the specific error only give the "pencil" graphic and very ambigious options, none of which are useful in combatting the issue. There is the "Path Error" inspection, under the category of HTML - but this also has no direct effect on this issue. I have a feeling that the newer MVC inspection options are perhaps insufficient in being able to suppress this particular one.

Answer (score 0):

Set to ignore that specific error by:
Open Soultion Errors Window by *ReSharper->Windows->**Soultion Errors Window***.
Right-click annoying error and select ***Ignore Error***.

See [answer for another error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9500326/1187616) for more explanation.

Comment: Thanks for that - I thought this would actually help, but after letting the Solution-Wide analysis run and ignoring ALL the errors in my view, despite the fact they all show up as ignored/greyed out in the Solution Errors window - the red underlines still appear in the views.